# tf.unstack with dynamic shape

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to unstack a Tensor because I need a sequence as input for the RNN. I am using variable sequence lengths which prevents me from correctly using `tf.unstack`.

```
def MapToSequences(x):
    # x.get_shape().as_list() = [64, 1, None, 512]
    x = tf.squeeze(x)
    # tf.shape(x) = [None, None, None], at runtime would be [64, seqlen, 512]
    x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    # [seqlen, 64, 512]
    # Here I'd like to unstack with seqlen as num
    x = tf.unstack(x) # Cannot infer num from shape (?, ?, ?)
    return x
```

I tried using `tf.shape(x)` to infer the seqlen and use it as `num`, but I get `Expected int for argument 'num' not <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>`

Comment: This isn't supported -- the number of outputs has to be known during graph compilation time. However, each output can have arbitrary length.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this may be answered elsewhere, but here's an answer here. You cannot use `tf.unstack` with non-inferrable dimensions. 
This is because of how tensorflow is designed with computation graphs defining transformations of Tensors. Each operation adds a node, and each Tensor is an edge between Nodes. When you `tf.unstack` a Tensor you generate multiple new Tensors (edges). If the number of new tensors created from a `tf.unstack` operation is undefined then the computation graph has an undefined number of edges which must not be.
Operations that don't add multiple new edges to the graph are allowed to have input Tensors with inferred dimensions (most operations).

To get around this one has two choices useful for the case of batched operations, i.e. in the case when you are trying to `tf.unstack` a Tensor with dimensions `(batch_size, ...)` and `batch_size` is inferrable.

### Choice 1

I would use the `batch_shape` argument to `keras.topology.Input`.
The weight Tensors produced will always be interchangable with another model generated with different `batch_size`.

Unless you need access to the computation graph with that non-inferrable dimension there is no reason why you should not that this route.

## Choice 2

A second option, in the case when you know a maximal `batch_size`, is to use [`tf.dynamic_partition`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition).

```
tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,10))
partitions = tf.range(max_batch_size)
num_partitions = max_batch_size
partitioned = tf.dynamic_partition(tensor, partitions, num_partitions, name='dynamic_unstack')
```

When you actually give a `batch_size` it will produce unstacked Tesors for the first `batch_size` indices, and `[]` empty Tensors for the rest.

Comment: But can I remove the empty Tensors?

Comment: What I tried show that the partitions need to have exact number of dimension with the first dimension of tensor. Otherwise, the program crashes. It means that this method does NOT work for unknown input shape. num_partitions is OK for bigger, but not for "partitions".

Comment: @Brandon, yes you are correct, and this comment saves my day! My final solve is ```num_partitions = max_batch_size``` and ```partitions = tf.range(tf.shape(tensor)[0])```