# tf.dynamic_partition get non-empty tensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using `tf.dynamic_partition` to get a dynamic split of a tensor, which can not infer the size. Using the answer (Choice 2) of this  [tf.unstack with dynamic shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404056/tf-unstack-with-dynamic-shape) , I create this experimental code, where the idea is that after processing with `tf.dynamic_partition` create some sort of filtering when the tensor has `tf.size` == 0, so a new list would be created that obtains only the non-empty tensors `tf.size`> 0

I need to have the list of non-empty tensors at the moment of creating the operations, because afterwards I need to create new operations on this list.

```
import tensorflow as tf


data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2))
partitions = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
max_partitions = 10

dp = tf.dynamic_partition(
    data,
    partitions,
    max_partitions,
    name="DynamicPartition"
)
new_dp = []
for tensor in dp:
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_rank_at_least(tensor, 1), tf.assert_greater(tf.size(tensor), 0)]):
          new_dp.append(tensor)

array = [[1,1],
         [1,1],
         [1,1],
         [1,1],
         [1,1],
         [2,2],
         [2,2],
         [2,2]]
order = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]


with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run([dp], 
                      feed_dict={
                        data:array,
                        partitions:order
                      })
    print(result)
```

The problem is that this experiment is not working, because the output is the list created by `tf.dynamic_partition` in which you can see all the tensors, both the non-empty and the empty

```
[[array([[2., 2.],
   [2., 2.],
   [2., 2.]], dtype=float32), array([[1., 1.],
   [1., 1.],
   [1., 1.],
   [1., 1.],
   [1., 1.]], dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32)]]
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: The assert ops just check conditions at runtime and fail if they are not met, but they do not affect the result that you get. The problem is that what tensors are empty or not depends on the input data, so you cannot possibly figure it out _before_ feeding the data and running the model. Can you give some more context as to what do you need this for? For the example that you posted, the recommended solution would be to evaluate `dp` (not `[dp]`) and filter `result` after the call to `run` (`result = [r in result if r.size() > 0]`).

Comment: I need to have the list of non-empty tensors at the moment of creating the operations, because afterwards I need to create new operations on this list.

Comment: What I mean is, you cannot discard any of the tensor at the moment of creation, because all of them _could_ be useful. Let's say you somehow figure out you should skip the fourth output in the list; but then you can always feed some `partitions` with a `4` in it, and you would lose some numbers. You can apply operations that do different things depending on the size, but the actual size can only be known when you feed the data. Maybe knowing what kind of operations you intend to create with this tensors (and why you need them to be non-empty) would help to find a workaround.