# Fix batch size in custom loss function (to be able to use unstack)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created a custom loss function by subclassing from `keras.losses.Loss`. Inside the method `call(self, y_true, y_pred)` I want to unstack the tensor `y_true`, but this does not work since it is of shape `(None,13,13,5,25)`, i.e. the batch dimension is unknown. Is there a way of fixing the batch dimension during training, such that the input to the `call()` method is - say - `(8,13,13,5,25)`?

During `model.fit()` I feed the model batches from a generator dataset, i.e. I do sth. like this:

```
BATCH_SIZE=8
train_batches = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

I tried to add an extra `InputLayer()` with a fixed `batch_size` to my model. `model.summary()` then tells me that the layers inside of the model have a defined batch size, so this looks all good, but the `y_true` in the `call()` method of the loss function still has shape `(None,13,13,5,25)`.

I also tried to replace `unstack()` by `dynamic_partition` as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404056/tf-unstack-with-dynamic-shape), but then the elements of the list that this produces still have `None` as the first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out: the problem goes away and the batch size is defined inside the call method if I set `drop_remainder=True` when batching the dataset:

```
dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
```