# How to tile rows for different times in TF1.x?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a batch of data with shape [?, dim],

```
x=[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

and a tensor indicates repetition number for each row with shape [?,1], say:

```
rep_nums=[[1],[2],[1],[3],[1]]
```

and expecting result to be :

```
[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

I tried dynamic_partition as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404056/tf-unstack-with-dynamic-shape) mentioned, but only works in TF2.x, which not compatible my pre-exist project.

Answer (score 0):

I think tf.repeat will help.

```
import tensorflow as tf

c1 = tf.constant([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

times = tf.constant([1, 2, 1, 3, 1])

res = tf.repeat(c1, times, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(res))
```